# Get a value from twig to angular

Tags: angular, symfony

I'm trying to pass a variable from twig to angular.
I'm using data binding, don't know if this is the good way.

Here is my twig page :

```
{% block mainContainer %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="schedule">
            <schedule [reference]="{{ project.getReference }}">Chargement en cours</schedule>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the angular page app.component :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {ScheduleService} from './service/schedule.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'schedule',
    providers: [ScheduleService],
    template: `
       <h1>Hello world</h1>
`
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() reference: string;
    constructor(private scheduleService: ScheduleService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.scheduleService.initialLoad();
    }
}
```

I want to get the reference value to use it in my angular page.
Any thoughts ?
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, but I still can't get the value in app.component page.

Comment: by name of `getReference`, it seems like it is a method.. is it?

Comment: Yep, it is a Symfony method, called in the twig page, it gets the reference of a project. this method works. When I inspect the code, I can see the reference I want in the source code of the page.

Comment: you should chabnge it to `project.getReference()` then

Comment: Ok, but this is not the issue, even when I enter a value myself ([reference]="value") I still can't access to it in angular.

Comment: Anyone to help ?

Comment: The reason why I couldn't get the reference is because i am passing a variable to a root node, this can't be done.

Comment: then what you did ??

Comment: I passed it via a <div> and used ElementRef to get it.